# Building DRAMpower

Tags: gcc, memory, simulation, xerces-c, gem5

So i want to build the DRAMpower to simulate the DRAM power model . I have all the dependecies installed that are required such as gcc and libxerces-c-dev. i then run the following command

```
 make -j4

g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat- 
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g   
-std=c++0x -MMD -MF src/TraceParser.d -iquote src -o src/TraceParser.o 
-c src/TraceParser.cc
 g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat- 
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wall -Werror -g   -std=c++0x 
-MMD -MF src/CmdScheduler.d -iquote src -o src/CmdScheduler.o -c 
src/CmdScheduler.cc
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat- 
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g   
-std=c++0x -MMD -MF src/cli/drampower.d -iquote src -o 
src/cli/drampower.o -c src/cli/drampower.cc
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat- 
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g   
-std=c++0x -MMD -MF src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.d -iquote src -o 
src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.o -c src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.cc
In file included from src/CommandAnalysis.h:55:0,
             from src/TraceParser.h:46,
             from src/TraceParser.cc:37:
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are 
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
^~~~~
In file included from src/CommandAnalysis.h:55:0,
             from src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.h:48,
             from src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.cc:42:
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are 
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
^~~~~
In file included from src/CmdScheduler.h:47:0,
             from src/CmdScheduler.cc:37:
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are  
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
^~~~~
In file included from src/CommandAnalysis.h:55:0,
             from src/MemoryPowerModel.h:49,
             from src/cli/drampower.cc:44:
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are 
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
^~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.o' 
failed
make: *** [src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'src/cli/drampower.o' failed
make: *** [src/cli/drampower.o] Error 1
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'src/TraceParser.o' failed
make: *** [src/TraceParser.o] Error 1
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'src/CmdScheduler.o' failed
make: *** [src/CmdScheduler.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what does the specific error mean and how to i get around it ?

Comment: Also open an issue in their issue tracker: https://github.com/tukl-msd/DRAMPower/issues that is your best bet.